# Travis CI - conditional 'before_deploy' script per each deploy provider

Tags: deployment, automation, continuous-integration, travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I am trying to deploy with Travis CI to 2 different providers(npm, firebase), my `.travis.yml` file looks something like this:

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - /v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/

install:
  - yarn

before_deploy:
  # first provider
  - yarn build:storybook
  # second provider
  - yarn build:library
  - cp package.json lib/
  - cd lib

deploy:
  - provider: firebase
    ...
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: npm
    ...
    on:
      tags: true
      all_branches: true
```

Now I would like to trigger `#first provider` block inside `before_deploy` only when I am deploying to firebase (master).

Is there some way to have a condition inside `before_deploy`? Or even a `only: -branch-name` inside `before_deploy`?

Comment: Have you tried using a [build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/)?

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz, how exactly could a build matrix help my case?

Comment: Never mind, I thought using a build matrix would solve this issue, but after trying myself I saw that it doesn't. You should post this question on [Travis CI's forum](https://travis-ci.community) or [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/new).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your condition as a bash script:

```
before_deploy:
  # first provider
  - |
    if [[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH != $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH && $TRAVIS_BRANCH = 'master ]]; then
      yarn build:storybook
    fi
  # second provider
  - yarn build:library
  - cp package.json lib/
  - cd lib
```

What this does is prevent the script from running `yarn build:storybook` when someone makes a new pull request to master; but only runs when the master branch is built by travis due to a push (or whatever triggers the build).

See here for more variables:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables